# compile xml file component

Tags: c#, xml

I have a simple question, is there any C# component that takes xml file and view it as browsers do .. I mean the component will compile the xml file and view it, do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: What do you mean by "compile" in this case?

Comment: I mean the component will compile the file and view it as in internet browsers.

Comment: Do you mean to validate the xml ?

Comment: There is a web browser component in WinForms/WPF that could be used to avoid any such work and simply allow IE to render it for you...

Comment: I don't know what "validate" means !

Comment: I think he doesnt want to validate it but just be able to open it like IE does preformating the colors and stuff from the xml and displaying it at screen. Like Reddog suggested you should just use web components.

Comment: The google term is "pretty print xml"

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters have suggested, you could go for the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control, which is effectively a WPF wrapper for the Internet Explorer engine. However, this component tends to be somewhat heavyweight, since it’s an entire HTML engine; if you want something lightweight which integrates more smoothly into your application, you could go for a third-party XML-rendering component, such as the [WPF XML Document Viewer Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71069/A-Simple-WPF-XML-Document-Viewer-Control) available on Code Project.